# How to differentiate 'normal transaction' values from 'internal transaction' values, avoiding duplicate values

Tags: ether, etherscan, internal-transactions, explorer-api

I'm aggregating data from the Etherscan API and I'm trying to add all normal transactions and internal transactions together and then calculating the balance of ETH for a wallet based on the past transactions.

However, I have run into a problem where I don't know how to precisely merge normal and internal transactions in a good way. **The problem is:**

*Four things can happen, as I see it:*

1. The normal transaction have a ETH value
2. The normal transaction has no ETH value but a value transfer appears in the internal transaction
3. The normal transaction has a ETH value and another value transfer also appears in the internal transaction
4. The normal transaction has a ETH value **and the same value transfer** also appears in the internal transaction

In other words in case 4 I get duplicate data, meaning that f.eg. instead of a transaction value adding 1 ETH to a wallet balance, it would add 2 ETH (one from the normal transaction log and one from the internal transaction log).

How can I separate ETH value transfers and avoid duplicate transfers? Meaning how can I correctly account for all 4 possible scenarios above.

Hope I made myself clear, please ask more questions if unclear, thanks in advance!